# Pikaday default value is being modified

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I have a field to set date to. This field could have a default value in format YYYYMMDD and it's being transformed to a correct format DD.MM.YYYY, which is understandable for operators. Don't ask me why, it's an ancient system and no, I can't rewrite it since it's using big backends.

I just need to add simple datepicker to those fields. I have chosen Pikaday, which is lightweight and simple enough for this particular task. My typical use-case looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" value="20150515" customType="date">
<img src="img/icon.gif" id="datepicker-button" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pikaday.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css">
<script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pikaday.js"></script>
<script>
    var picker = new Pikaday(
    {
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        trigger: document.getElementById('datepicker-button'),
        firstDay: 1,
        yearRange: [1900,2020],
        onSelect: function() {
            var date = document.createTextNode(this.getMoment().format('DD.MM.YYYY') + ' ');
            document.getElementById('selected').appendChild(date);
        }
    });
    field.parentNode.insertBefore(picker.el, field.nextSibling);
</script>
```

The original piece of code is the input tag. The rest is my new datepicker functionality.

And now, what's the problem.
The problem is the default value. Let's say that default value is 20151023. The customType attribute should make a correct date of 23.10.2015 but the following Pikaday snippet makes a date of 20.03.1023. I don't know why. I don't understand javascript well but I guess that onSelect param is just a kind of anonymous callback function to be called only in case when user clicks the datepicker button.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks, JiKra

EDIT:

There seems to be a different problem. If there comes any value from backend, it's in the value format like 20151023. And there is an ancient javascript file with some function, that parses the value and creates a proper format 23.10.2015. Problem is that my Pikaday constructor is being called before that ancient parser. Even when I use promising snippet by jazZRo to modify value before Pikaday call, that ancient parser freaks out because it expects a YYYYMMDD format.
So, what I need is either call my stuff after the ancient parser or prohibit that onSelect callback function in Pikaday constructor to not run on page load.

Is that possible?

Comment: 20151023 is interpreted by momentjs as 20-15-1023 (DD-MM-YYYY) and corrects the month value to 12 + 3 = March. I have no idea where you see that and have created [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/05fyr368/) Can you update and paste the link in a comment to show the exact problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/05fyr368/2/

Comment: Problem is with the default format of date. Default in Pikaday is YYYY-MM-DD which is fine with that but we are using DD.MM.YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to use momentjs to convert the value of the input before it is being used by Pickaday:

```
(function() {
    var moment = window.moment(document.getElementById('datepicker').value, 'DDMMYYYY');
    document.getElementById('datepicker').value = moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
})();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/05fyr368/3/